# Make website appear on Google regardless of PHP routing

Tags: php, routes, seo

Over the past few days, I have been working on a new website. As of now, I have chosen to go with something similar to that of an MVC: I am using PHP for routing to other pages depending on a value retrieved by `GET`, changing some settings inside the `.htaccess`.

When I search for my website on Google, I find three links: one for the website and two for different subdomains:

> www.example.com
> sub.example.com
> one.example.com

The structure of the links on my website looks like this, because of the routing:

> www.example.com/test/be
> dev.example.com/that/this

This is my `.htaccess` in case you need it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
```

All the different parts of the website are linked together with `a href`, but I worry that may not be enough to make it fully *SEO*.

Is this a problem going to be a problem? Is there anything I can do about it?

**Edit:** what I am asking is whether or not this type of layout will be a problem regarding SEO. If that is the case, my follow-up question is what way I would go about fixing it, which most certainly would be a programming-related task (and so the question is not off-topic).

Comment: *Off-topic*, as this has nothing to do with programming itself. Also, what is the **problem**? I don't see anything *not* working, so what is your question exactly?

Comment: You might consider adding `R=301` to your last rewrite rule, so Google knows it's a permanent location and not just a temporary redirect. Other than that I think you should be fine.

Comment: @Nytrix I made an edit to the question answering your question.